# TYPO3 changing an extension with own extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-extensions

I'm trying to create a extension to modify fields in a different extension.
My extension needs to add and disable fields in fe_users over the TSConfig Page.

Ive looked over google how to do this with a own extension. But I didn't find anything usefull that I could work with.

(*Edited*)

The admin shouldn't be able to see these fields:

- Company
- Name
- Middle name
- Address
- Zipcode
- Land
- Phone
- Fax
- www
- Image
- TSConfig
- Bind a Domain
- Redirect after login
- Start
- Stop
- Record Type

These fields should be added

- Customer (INT, not able to edit on display) Manditory
- swissaxis_id (INT, Unique number) if possible only displayable and
  not editing possibility
- shop_rights (Textarea, No defined Value. The Rights will be saved
  there serialised.)

**fe_groups**

These fields shouldn't be displayed to any Admin

- Bind a domain
- TSConfig
- Redirect after login
- Record Type

I'm thankfull for any Feedback possible.

Comment: What do you mean by 'disabling' fields? Should they be hidden from backend users? Even admins? Or should they be visible but not editable? Does adding fields mean they should also be available through extbase / fluid?

Comment: The admin is usually the admin because he can see / edit anything. Is there a reason why you can't use backend user roles?

Comment: I'm building a extension to create a shop module for typo3. For this i need to set the fields in the extension and not the typo3 itself. The reason for this is, that the page will be half a page and half a shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link on how you add new fields to `fe_users`: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ExtendingTca/Index.html
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html

I'll give you an example from an old, makeshift extension `zusatzfelder` of mine that modifies the "pages" table. It's really old, please verify if everything is current. You can also look at any other, "real" extension...

ext_emconf.php (maybe created by extension_builder)

```
<?php

########################################################################
# Extension Manager/Repository config file for ext "zusatzfelder".
#
# Auto generated 29-08-2011 15:33
#
# Manual updates:
# Only the data in the array - everything else is removed by next
# writing. "version" and "dependencies" must not be touched!
########################################################################

$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array(
    'title' => 'Zusatzfelder',
    'description' => '',
    'category' => '',
    'author' => '',
    'author_email' => '',
    'shy' => '',
    'dependencies' => '',
    'conflicts' => '',
    'priority' => '',
    'module' => '',
    'state' => '',
    'internal' => '',
    'uploadfolder' => 0,
    'createDirs' => '',
    'modify_tables' => '',
    'clearCacheOnLoad' => 0,
    'lockType' => '',
    'author_company' => '',
    'version' => '0.0.0',
    'constraints' => array(
        'depends' => array(
        ),
        'conflicts' => array(
        ),
        'suggests' => array(
        ),
    ),
    '_md5_values_when_last_written' => 'a:8:{s:9:"ChangeLog";s:4:"5b94";s:10:"README.txt";s:4:"ee2d";s:12:"ext_icon.gif";s:4:"1bdc";s:14:"ext_tables.php";s:4:"474a";s:14:"ext_tables.sql";s:4:"ead9";s:16:"locallang_db.xml";s:4:"7a92";s:19:"doc/wizard_form.dat";s:4:"0cba";s:20:"doc/wizard_form.html";s:4:"29e8";}',
);

?>
```

ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE pages (
        tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title_addition tinytext,
        tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title tinytext,
        tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_disable int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

ext_tables.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}
$tempColumns = array (
    'tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title' => array (       
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:zusatzfelder/locallang_db.xml:pages.tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title',      
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'input',  
            'size' => '30',
        )
    ),
    'tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title_addition' => array (      
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:zusatzfelder/locallang_db.xml:pages.tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title_addition',     
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'input',  
            'size' => '30',
        )
    ),
    'tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_disable' => array (     
        'exclude' => 0,     
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:zusatzfelder/locallang_db.xml:pages.tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_disable',        
        'config' => array (
            'type' => 'check',  
            'default' => '0',
        )
    ),
);


\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('pages',$tempColumns,1);
// http://typo3-blog.net/tutorials/news/addtoalltcatypes.html
// PS: the "after:"... is for placement in the BE, stopped working last week...
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages','tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title;;;;1-1-1','','after:subtitle');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages','tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title_addition;;;;1-1-1','','after:subtitle');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('pages','tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_disable;;;;1-1-1','','after:subtitle');
?>
```

locallang_db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3locallang>
    <meta type="array">
        <type>database</type>
        <description>Language labels for database tables/fields belonging to extension 'zusatzfelder'</description>
    </meta>
    <data type="array">
        <languageKey index="default" type="array">
            <label index="pages.tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title_addition">Untermenu: Vorlauf Titel (zB. "Mehr zur")</label>
            <label index="pages.tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_title">Untermenu: Titellink anderer Text (Standard: Seitentitel; Leerschlag: kein Titel)</label>
            <label index="pages.tx_zusatzfelder_contentnav_disable">Untermenu ausblenden</label>
        </languageKey>
    </data>
</T3locallang>
```

That's all you need to add new fields  – you don't even need the locallang if you just prefer to do `'label' => 'My untranslated Label',` in ext_tables.php.

Comment: While the code as is should still work, all of your classes are deprecated. Also loadTCA() is not not needed at all anymore since the TCA is readily available since TYPO3 6.2.

Comment: sven, thanks, horrible! :-) I think I also posted it because I suspected that

Comment: I've updated the class for t3lib_extMgm and removed loadTCA

Comment: I will be trying this soon and will give you my feedback when i achieved something.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So i have tried this out. But for some odd reason the Fields aren't being implemented. If i then again go look in the Configuration i can see the new fields.

Comment: Maybe its better to use the tutorial from the first link in the answer than my old code, try it with that. Or kickstart a new extension with extension_builder and edit afterwards